# Why is my xmlFile not getting displayed when I start my app?

Tags: java, android, xml, file

so this is my code, which implements a Chronometer to my App:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Chronometer mChronometer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.isBaselineAligned();

        mChronometer = new Chronometer(this);

        // Set the initial value
        mChronometer.setText("00:10");
        layout.addView(mChronometer);

        Button startButton = new Button(this);
        startButton.setText("Start");
        startButton.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);
        layout.addView(startButton);

        Button stopButton = new Button(this);
        stopButton.setText("Stop");
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(mStopListener);
        layout.addView(stopButton);

        Button resetButton = new Button(this);
        resetButton.setText("Reset");
        resetButton.setOnClickListener(mResetListener);
        layout.addView(resetButton);

        setContentView(layout);
    }

    private void showElapsedTime() {
        long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mChronometer.getBase();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Elapsed milliseconds: " + elapsedMillis,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int stoppedMilliseconds = 0;

            String chronoText = mChronometer.getText().toString();
            String array[] = chronoText.split(":");
            if (array.length == 2) {
                stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 1000
                        + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 1000;
            } else if (array.length == 3) {
                stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000
                        + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 60 * 1000
                        + Integer.parseInt(array[2]) * 1000;
            }

            mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - stoppedMilliseconds);
            mChronometer.start();
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener mStopListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChronometer.stop();
            showElapsedTime();
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener mResetListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            showElapsedTime();
        }
    };
}
```

The problem is though, that when I start my App, everything I did in my xml file, won't be displayed on the App, everything I can see is the Chronometer and its Buttons. Did I overwrite my xml file in the java file or something like that?
In my xml file I am using a ScrollView as the rootView, if that matters in any way.

Thank you in advance,
Julian.

Comment: post your layout xml

Comment: you have write setContentView(layout); line so it will set the current view as layout which you have defined so it will not show the xml file which you have specify earlier, to show it and out this layout in side scroll view first create instance of scrollview and then add layout in scrollview

Comment: How can I add layout in scrollView ? Do I have to put two parameters into the setContentView()-method or is there a better way? Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Hello First of all in your class you are adding (R.layout.activity_main) to your view and at the end of the on create method again you are adding a layout to your view like this: 
        `setContentView(layout);`
so it override your view.... that's why your layout is not visible..... remove that dynamic view or by creating a layout in your xml file add that layout to that view so it will work....... hope it will help....;

Comment: Ah, I see the mistake, thank you! So how can I combine those two ? Or is there a more effective way ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response but as per your question if you want to add the dynamically created layout to your Scrollview then create a Linearlayout/Relativelayout and then create the instance of that layout and your dynamic view to that layout.. then you are done...@Julian